# Import Library in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: dll, import, shared-libraries

I have the headers SC2_CamExport.h, SC2_SDKStructures.h and the librariese SC2_Cam.lib, SC2_Cam.dll I want to include in a C++ project. I added the folder with the containing libraries and headers, but when I include the header SC2_CamExport.h, I have errors.

```
#ifdef dfsdfdsf
#if defined _WIN64
   #define SC2_SDK_FUNC
#else
   #define SC2_SDK_FUNC __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
#else
   #define SC2_SDK_FUNC __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {            //  Assume C declarations for C++
#endif  //C++

SC2_SDK_FUNC int WINAPI PCO_GetGeneral(HANDLE ph, PCO_General *strGeneral);

SC2_SDK_FUNC int WINAPI PCO_GetCameraType(HANDLE ph, PCO_CameraType *strCamType);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}       //  Assume C declarations for C++
#endif  //C++
```

So in the line of "SC2_SDK_FUNC int WINAPI PCO_GetGeneral(HANDLE ph, PCO_General *strGeneral);" I get an error "error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'PCO_GetGeneral'". I guess the main problem is that I am not able to import a DLL in C++ as mentioned in [Using .dll in Visual Studio 2010 C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136450/using-dll-in-visual-studio-2010-c). So anyway, I'm not sure what I have to do and how I can import this library. Do I just need to import the .lib file anyhow, or what is exactly the problem?

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked to include windows.h so that all windows commands are available.
so just insert

`#include <windows.h>`

at the beginning of your file

KR
Bernhard